# How to customize bootstrap modal like tinybox js popup

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have worked with tinybox. i saw when tinybox load content then a small div appear on screen with a loader icon. when content comes then loader icon goes and content set inside the tinybox popup.i am talking about this tinybox js http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/05/new-javascript-popup-box-tinybox.html

i want to achieve the same with bootstrap modal windows. i want when bootstrap modal will show then its height and width will be like my images posted with loader icon inside it but when content comes from server side then bootstrap dialog will resize gradually and nicely to fit the content inside it.

here i try to mean **gradually and nicely** in the past when i worked with jquery dialog then i did increase its height and width nicely with animate function because that looks good. here i try to mean the same that before appending content inside bootstrap dialog the dialog will resize gradually and nicely.

here i tried one but need small help.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Small Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" id="mybutton" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>
       <div style="display:none" id="anothermymodal">    

            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>This is a small modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
      </div>

</div>



  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content"  id="mycontent">              
         <div class="inner-div">
            <img src="http://mybusyicon.gif"/>           
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

here is jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/7t2fghtf/1/

if you test the example then you must notice bootstrap dialog size is huge which i do not want.

if i use css to minimize the  bootstrap dialog size then what logic or trick i should use to rezide  bootstrap dialog again to fit the content inside it properly.

see the picture
[image]

so when modal will be shown then modal will have small width with loader icon and when content comes from server side function then modal width will increase automatically to fit the content.

please guide me what i am trying to achieve. thanks

Comment: i checked your link but still modal has huge width. so i need to minimize the width. see my picture please. when content comes then width of the modal will increase gradually before setting the content inside it.

Comment: this is my jsfiddle and i am bit closer https://jsfiddle.net/7t2fghtf/5/

Answer (score 2):

Your code needed some changes

`<div class="container">
        <h2>Small Modal</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" id="mybutton" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>
        <div style="display:none" id="anothermymodal">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>This is a small modal.</p><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="loader">
                    <img src="#" /></div>
                <div id="mycontent" style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

Check complete code here,
https://jsfiddle.net/taimursaeed15/Lho9mkkz/1/

Comment: i up vote you for your effort but UI does not look good when big content added in modal. it would be better if we detect content height and width by jquery and then we need to increase the height and width of modal with jquery animate function and then add the content there with fade effect will be much better.